# In D3.js, what is the proper way to handle overlapping scatter plot to make it look prettier

Tags: java, css, reactjs, d3.js

Practising D3.js with a simple graph : **GDP x Population**
The first 3 dots from right to left are China, India and USA

**Problem1**
The huge population of China and India make the xScale look weird, any suggestion for this kind of issue ?

**Problem2**
the circles on bottom left are overlapping and look like a mess,
is there anything I can do with it or am I simply using the wrong graph ? Thanks

**Initial**
[image]

**Added a zoom on x-axis, better but overlapping problem still exists**

**x-axis Zoomed**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some of it is the nature of the data. This is why you'll often see reports based on x per 100k people vs x per total population. It levels the playing field. You could also look at the different D3 scales. I assume this was made with the Linear scale. However, D3 comes natively with several more that might   help with the appearance.
[Check out the scales here.](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale)

You can also use some third-party scales such as made available by the Simple Statistics plugin or from other authors. [Here's a nice article on scales.](https://observablehq.com/@d3/quantile-quantize-and-threshold-scales)

Second, plot charts are made for showing where statistics group. So overlapping is kind of the point.